# Using Ansible to configure F5 through SSH Tunnel

Tags: python, ansible, ssh-tunnel, f5

I'm currently having a problem running an Ansible F5 playbook via an SSH Bastion host to configure an F5 Device, not sure where the issue could be at this stage.

BIGSUDS, SUDS, F5-SDK all installed via pip

My Playbook
--- f5play.yml ----

```
---
- hosts: f5_devices
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: f5 test
    bigip_facts:
      server: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      password: "{{ ansible_ssh_pass }}"
      include: "interface"
      validate_certs: false
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: out

  - debug: msg= "{{ out }}"
```

I have a "group_vars" directory with an "f5_devices" directory that contains my vault.yml and vars.yml

vars.yml contains my extra proxy info, to jump through an intermediate ssh host before jumping to the f5, It has been successfully used with this setup before to get to Cisco devices.

---

inventory file = ansible_hosts

```
[f5_devices]
F5-LTM1  ansible_user=admin
```

---

--vars.yml--

```
ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ vault_ansible_ssh_pass }}"
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -v bastion1" -o 
StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

---

ansible-playbook -i ansible_hosts f5play.yml --ask-vault-pass -vvv

UPDATE - added "delegate_to: localhost"
now, still this error

```
            "session": false,
            "state": "present",
            "user": "admin",
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "received exception: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service 
not known>\ntraceback: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File 
\"/tmp/ansible_cdaERk/ansible_module_bigip_facts.py\", line 1664, in main\n    
saved_active_folder = f5.get_active_folder()\n  File 
\"/tmp/ansible_cdaERk/ansible_module_bigip_facts.py\", line 148, in 
get_active_folder\n    return self.api.System.Session.get_active_folder()\n  
File \"/home/mike/Proj/ansible/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bigsuds.py\", 
line 360, in __getattr__\n    client = self._client_creator('%s.%s' % 
(self._name, attr))\n  File \"/home/mike/Proj/ansible/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/bigsuds.py\", line 170, in _create_client\n    raise 
ConnectionError(str(e))\nConnectionError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or 
service not known>\n"
}
```

I forgot to add, this is running in a virtual environment (virtualenv ansible)

Any help would be 'greatly' appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess, you should:

- remove `connection: local`
- remove ssh and proxy settings for `f5_devices` group
- add `bastion1` host to your inventory
- then `delegate_to: bastion1`

this way Ansible will connect to your bastion host and execute `bigip_facts` module from there targeting your f5 devices.

Comment: I commented out the ssh_common_args, removed the connection: local and delegated to Bastion1 and now have a new error


     fatal: [F5-LTM1]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: 
     mux_client_request_session: out of sequence reply: my id 1 theirs 2\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
}

Comment: I'm wondering if anyone has even tried this before or if it's even possible since you need to SSH through an intermediate host in order to communicate using the F5  iControl API??

Comment: I just saw something about having bigsuds installed on the jump host which is a shame as I wanted to avoid having to touch the jumphost software.